# How to prevent two exterior painted surfaces from sticking?

Tags: paint, exterior, preparation

This question needs no editing, but feel free to edit it into one that asks for a hard fact answer backed up by one or more reliable sources, like, well I can't think of any, cause you know, peeling paint, in all it's non-fractal splendid variation remains one of those, well, one of those unmentionables, or at least unmentioned outside of improperly closed circles.

I've been using kitchen wax paper in between parts to keep to keep paint from peeling dues to the painted surface from sticking to another surface, often painted as well, when attaching the two so that paint remains intact if/when I need to separate them in the future.

For example, when I attach a cleat to an interior painted wall, I'll place a layer or two of wax paper between the two.

For example, Behr exterior semi gloss in my experience is not truly dry even after a month of 80 degree weather.  So attaching prepainted pickets to prepainted rails has the sticking problem.

It occurred to me that I could spray some kind of mold-release, or furniture polish, or pure wax onto one of the surfaces, then after assembly wash the 'overspray' off the non-mating areas.  Something rather cheap, must be non-toxic for plants and animals.

What is your recommended solution for preventing paint peeling when separating a painted surface?

Comment: How often are you removing pickets from your fence that this is a problem? How often are you removing things from interior walls? If you have a "cleat" attached to the wall, there will be some holes left when you remove it that will need to be filled & painted, so just paint over the bit of paint that peels up, too... Also, heat helps paint dry, but if it's 80° and 80% Rh, then your paint won't dry. You need to run the AC, too - even if it's just to get the paint to dry. Or, you're putting it on _way_ too thick...

Comment: Exterior ......

Comment: If you're painting a fence post & picket and they're still sticky after a month, the only thing I can think of is that you're glooping the paint on _way_ too thick, or that you live somewhere where there's 99.9% humidity all the time.

Comment: Think more ....

Answer (score 1):

My local Ace didn't have any spray product. But on the way home I thought of a technique that I'll use today for assembling the picket fence panels.

Place a layer of wax paper along the entire length of the rail, aligned with the top edge, stapled in place where the pickets will go.  Use the bottom edge as a guide to trim off the excess. Position a picket, slip a pair of thin 2"x6" sheet of plastic such as comb-binding covers under the picket 1/4" underneath, along the left and right picket edges parallel to them. Nail the picket to the rail. Trim the wax paper to the picket width. Remove the 2x6 plastic cutting protectors that kept the blade from scoring the paint on the rails. Sink the nails.

Edit: Done. This worked really well for me.  Will use it again as situations arise.  The spray wax did seem to have the potential to be easier, but this technique with wax paper avoided the overspray clean up mess.

Comment: Seriously, you're _nailing_ the pickets on, but you're worried about the paint sticking? A bit of peeled paint will be the _least_ of your worries should you ever need to disassemble this fence, but you go right ahead and make the assembly process take 10 times longer than necessary.

Comment: This is a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: Stainless steel ring shank 2" waffle head siding nails for vintage pickets on 21' rails ripped from a shipping crate 2x10 that transported spec pipe from Germany.

Comment: and your point is?????

Comment: and you're nailing the pickets on?